# rails - belongs_to any different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some models in my database:

```
- customer
    has_many documents
- charts
    has_many documents
- pages
    has_many documents
```

Any of models above can have many **documents**.

How can I do this in the Document model? Is there any relationship can accept different models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. This concept is called **polymorphic association** and can be done like this using Ruby on Rails:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents, as: :owner
```

It uses 2 columns to work: one column to save the owner's type, and a second column to save th owner's id:

```
Document.create(owner_type: 'Customer', owner_id: customer.id)
```

Then, you can call the method `.owner` on the document object:

```
doc = Document.first
doc.owner # => Can either return a Customer, Chart or Page record
```

---

You might want to **add some security** around this, something to prevent from creating documents for a owner that is not supposed to have this relation:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
  validates :owner_type, inclusion: { in: %w( Customer Chart Page ) }
```

This will prevent from creating documents like this:

```
Document.create(owner_type: 'kittyCat', owner_id: 77) # won't work
```

Comment: thanks! so in my Document migration I need those two columns?

Comment: @user3175226 yes you need to explicitly create the 2 columns (in this case named `owner_type` and `owner_id`) (if it was `belongs_to :something, polymorphic: true`, the columns would have been `something_type` and `something_id`)